# Best practices for importing libraries in multimodule Android project

Tags: android, gradle

Let's say I have an Android project with 4 modules: `app`,`feature1`, `feature2`, `feature3` and `common`.

`app` depends on all three `feature*` modules. `feature*` modules do not depend on each other, but they depend on `common`.

If I have a library which is used in two of them (let's say I'm using Retrofit in `feature1` and `feature2`), which solution is considered as the better practice?

1. `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'` both in the `feature1` and `feature2` gradle files
2. `api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'` in the `common` gradle file

The first solution provides more control - compiler won't allow me to use Retrofit in `feature3` unless I explicitly create this dependency i the gradle file. Second one, however, leads to less amount of code, without duplication (yes, I know, I can extract constant to reduce code duplication, but still, there will be more code than in the second approach).

Comment: As the purpose of modules is to be reused, in the second solution, if you want to use the feature3 module by itself (without modules 1 and 2) you end importing an entire library that you don't use (Retrofit in your example), which make your app bigger and takes more time to build. So I'd go for the first solution

Answer (score 0):

Create `feature.gradle` file with common dependencies and other common code in the project folder. In your `feature1`'s and `feature2`'s `build.gradle` add this line:

```
apply from: rootProject.file('feature.gradle')
```

Comment: I think, this is similar (maybe a little better) approach to the one I've mentioned: putting common dependencies in the `common` module - every module has an access to all dependencies, even if is not using them.
The purpose of my question was to get an answer: which one is considered as better practice, which one works better in which case or simply which one is preferred by the developers who have tried both.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's better to import needed libraries only where you need. If you're cared about duplication of code, than why you are not care that you have duplication in 'app' and 'common' build.gradle's:

```
implementation project(':feature1')
implementation project(':feature2')
implementation project(':feature3')
```

So i think it doesn't matter and it's better to import libraries only where you need.